# Pandas: result column by aggregating entire row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe containing tuples of booleans (real value, predicted value) and want to create new columns containing the amount of true/false positives/negatives.
[image: pandas dataframe]
I know i could loop through the indices and set the column value for that index after looping through the entire row, but i believe that's a pandas anti-pattern.
Is there a cleaner and more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative would be to check the whole dataframe for `(True,False)` values and sum the amount of matches along the columns axis (`sum(axis=1)`).

```py
df['false_positives'] = df.apply(lambda x: x==(True,False)).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: That's cleaner than my solution, thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work fine:

```
def count_false_positives(row):
  count = 0
  for el in df.columns:
    if(row[el][0] and not row[el][1]): 
      count+=1
  return count

df.false_positives = df.apply(lambda row: count_false_positives(row), axis=1)
```